# Heroku deploy fails with react and next js

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

My react/next js app works perfectly fine (zero errors/warnings) in my localhost and somehow fails to deploy on Heroku. 
When I deploy, I consistently get the same error stating that my `posts` array (in `pages/landing.js`) is undefined.

I tried debugging and creating a support ticket as suggested in the logs, but Heroku support was unable to help.

I added log statements as log 1,2, what are the posts,3 and in the deploy logs, I only see "log 3 landing js undefined" so it somehow skips the API call and the client-side log from the `pages.index.js`

This is what my code looks like:

```
// pages/index.js
import React from "react";
import Landing from "./landing";
import Layout from "../src/components/layout";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
import Error from "next/error";

const Index = ({ posts }) => (
  <Layout>
    <div>
      {console.log("what are the posts???", posts)}
      <Landing posts={posts} />
    </div>
  </Layout>
);

export default Index;

Index.getInitialProps = async () => {
  console.log("log 1");
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/posts");

  const json = await res.json();
  console.log("log 2 what is json", json);
  return { posts: json.posts };
};
```

```
//pages/landing.js
import React from "react";
import Navigation from "../src/components/navigation";
import Layout from "../src/components/layout";
import Link from "next/link";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

const Landing = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Navigation />
// ...
      {console.log("log 3 landing js ", posts)}
            {posts.map(post => (
              <h1>post.title</h1>
            ))}
      <Navigation />
    <Layout>
export default Landing;
```

```
//package.json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.2.0",
    "npm": "6.4.1",
    "yarn": "1.13.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "^9.1.4",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.md$/,
      use: "raw-loader"
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```

And finally,the Heroku deploy log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.2.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.4.1
       engines.yarn (package.json):  1.13.0

       Resolving node version 12.2.0...
       Downloading and installing node 12.2.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.4.1 (replacing 6.9.0)...
       npm 6.4.1 installed
       Resolving yarn version 1.13.0...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.13.0)...
       Installed yarn 1.13.0

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.13.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > bootstrap@4.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3".
       warning " > bootstrap@4.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.16.0".
       warning " > raw-loader@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
       warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 52.24s.

-----> Build
       Running build (yarn)
       yarn run v1.13.0
       $ next build
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
       This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
       You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
       https://nextjs.org/telemetry


       Compiled successfully.

       Automatically optimizing pages...
       log 3 landing js  undefined
Error occurred prerendering page "/landing": TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Landing (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/.next/server/static/ATrNApXPLQXluLPvZMJ2m/pages/landing.js:4246:32)
    at d (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:498)
    at Za (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:39:16)
    at a.b.render (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:476)
    at a.b.read (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:18)
    at renderToString (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:54:364)
    at render (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:81:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:323:20)
    at /tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/.next/server/static/ATrNApXPLQXluLPvZMJ2m/pages/_document.js:2046:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors
    at _default (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:15:788)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
    at async build (/tmp/build_e6fcf8d3b8da4774fe2ba078e3d46384/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:20:145)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `landing` page does not have a `getInitialProps`, next.js is trying to prerender it, so the `post` is undefined. One of the things you could do is to move your `landing` into components.

If you need `posts` on every page, you may use `getInitialProps` in a custom app, like it's described [in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-app)

---

*the below is actually an answer to another question*

I guess, using `localhost:3000` on your Heroku instance is not quite correct. Instead, you could get the api page's url from the request headers, so your `getInititalProps` could look similar to this:

```
Index.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  if (ctx.req) {
    const host = ctx.req.headers['x-forwarded-host'];
    const proto = ctx.req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];
    const port =  ctx.req.headers['x-forwarded-port'];

    const res = await fetch(`${proto}//${host}:${port}/api/posts`);

    const json = await res.json();
    return { posts: json.posts };
  } else {
    // otherwise we are in the browser
    const res = await fetch(`/api/posts`);

    const json = await res.json();
    return { posts: json.posts };
  }
}
```

---

I've looked it up here: https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/calling-pages-api-directly-in-ssr-getinitialprops~8416c24b-19dc-46eb-aab7-8943a0c4a92e

Comment: I received the same error: ```       Automatically optimizing pages...
       log 3 landing js  undefined
Error occurred prerendering page "/landing": TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined``` It somehow completely skips getInitialprops call

Comment: @Matt I'm sorry, I noticed the `localhost` and immediately began to write an answer. I've updated it with a more relevant idea. Please let me know if it would help.

Comment: You were right about the root cause! I didn't move it the components but got rid of the landing and moved it to index.js and that made it work. But moving to land to components would make it clearer so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For successfull deployment of nextjs app in heroku you need to do one small modification in package.json file

update the start command to: "start": "next start -p $PORT"

Before:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}
```

After:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start -p $PORT"
}
```